# Multiple linear gradients left top directions

Tags: css, gradient

I need to create a square element with gradients to achieve same way as border or box-shadow, because when skewing and rotating the element a slight line appear on the border.

As far as I can get is using multiple gradients with different directions, but it looks like it's not possible (or I don't know how)

I have tried with this but it doesn't work (with its vendor-prefixes):

```
  background:
     linear-gradient( top, white 0%, white 5%, red 5%, red 95%,white 95%, white 100%),
     linear-gradient( left,white 0%, white 5%, red 5%, red 95%,white 95%, white 100%)
  ;
```

Have created a [codepen](http://codepen.io/rafamacias/pen/dbgEn) to show what want to achieve and why can't use border (with box-shadow still the same issue)

I have also tried with an :after and it works, but I need an approach without :after pseudo-element.

Thanks!

Comment: This cannot be done with one element (so far). You must use second elment like `:after`

Comment: Have you tried the same code, but with `transparent` instead of `red` for the 1nd gradient?

Comment: Thanks @IlyaStreltsyn, now it work, without the :after, setting the transparent in the first gradient and the color in the second. Now I understand the logic and it seems right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to  [Ilya Streltsyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2533215/ilya-streltsyn) I solved the problem.

The thing is, when using gradients, the order of the code is important. So basically will work:

```
background: 
    -webkit-linear-gradient( top,white 0%, white 5%, transparent 5%, transparent 95%,white 95%, white 100%),
    -webkit-linear-gradient( left,white 0%, white 5%, red 5%, red  95%,white 95%, white 100%);
```

}

Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/rafamacias/pen/dbgEn)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the :after element with the middle color set as transparent.

Comment: I've tried with that and it works, adding a left:-1px and width += 2px  but I still want to do it without :after if possible.